# When creating Azure releases, how do I tie an existing stage to a different artifact?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Currently, we have a number of stages associated with one of our artifacts.  Notice the two lines coming out of one of the artifacts ...

[image]

I would like to move one of the stages to the artifact beneath it.  I'm unclear how to do this.  When I click on the "Pre-deployment conditions" graphic to the left of the stage

[image]

and then click on the "After Release" button under "Triggers"

[image]

the artifact I want does not appear in the "Add" dropdown.  What populates this menu and how can I get my other artifact to appear under there so I can move my stage?

Comment: Hi @Dave. Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Kevin, Thanks for your response.  I added a follow-up question to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Notice the two lines coming out of one of the artifacts ...

In the release, this is not a connection of a single artifact but a connection of the entire artifacts. Two lines point to the [Release Primary source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops#primary-source).

I am afraid that you can't display a stage on the UI to connect to a single artifact by configuring release.

In Release Pipeline, the stage can connect to the entire artifacts and not only one of them.

**Workaround:**

You can achieve similar functions by setting Artifacts filter and Select `Artifact download` for each stage.

For example:

**Stage 1 -> Artifacts Filter: Include -> Artifacts 1  Exclude -> Artifacts 2**

Then Stage 1 will only be triggered when artifact 1 triggers release.

And you could select to download the artifacts 1 in **Stage 1 -> Artifact download**.

[image]

In this case, no matter what trigger method is(e.g. Manually trigger,CD Trigger), a single stage will only use the corresponding artifacts.

On the other hand, this requirement is valuable.

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21), which is our main forum for product suggestions.

Comment: In your screen shot above, does that mean that the stage will only be triggered by a release of the artifact "_test" and not a release of "_testkevin77" because only the "Select All" checkbox is checked next to the "_test" artifact?

Comment: @Dave This is just to select the artifacts to be downloaded when running the stage. It has no connection with release trigger. To set the trigger artifacts, you need to set the **Artifacts filters** in **Pre-deployment conditions**.